# Numeric column in database serialized as text from REST-endpoint

Tags: postgresql, rust, serde, rust-diesel

I have a REST-endpoint that fetches some data from a postgresql-database. One of the columns is of type numeric. When I get data back this is serialized as text and not a number with a decimal-point.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, QueryableByName)]
pub struct Product {
    #[diesel(sql_type = Text)]
    pub name: String,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Numeric)]
    pub price: BigDecimal,
}

impl Product {
    pub fn find() -> Result<Vec<Product>, CustomError> {
        let q = "
select
  name,
  price
from
  products
order by
  sales_count desc,
  name asc
";

        let mut conn = db::connection()?;
        let p: Vec<Product> = diesel::sql_query(q)
            .get_results(&mut conn)?;
        Ok(p)
    }
}

Cargo.toml:

diesel = { version = "2.0.2", features = ["postgres", "r2d2", "uuid", "chrono", "numeric", "serde_json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.148", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.89"
bigdecimal = { version = "0.3.0", features = ["serde"] }

$ curl /products | jq
[
  {
    "name": "soda",
    "price": "5.000"
  },
  {
    "name": "ice",
    "price": "4.000"
  }
]
```

The price is used to calculate a sum at client-side and having price as decimal rather than text will avoid a conversion after being parsed. Can I change the REST-endpoint to send price as numeric/decimal-point?

Comment: `BigDecimal` [serializes only as a string](https://github.com/akubera/bigdecimal-rs/blob/272123eddc02aad5d1a331ded8eb6605ed2bea96/src/lib.rs#L1820-L1827). This is probably because it has arbitrary size and precision. The arbitrary size of `BigDecimal` means that it will not generally fit into the Javascript `Number` type for instance. You should handle the parsing yourself.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @PitaJ, it's probably a bad idea to serialize `BigDecimal`s as numbers, since your client is unlikely to be able to handle arbitrary precision. That said, it's possible.

`serde_json` has an `arbitrary_precision` feature. Inconveniently, this does not make `BigDecimal` magically work. For the most part, it just changes `serde_json::Number` to be a `String` internally, and adds an internal [special field name](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/ce53b862b9a09130cdd5363088135b4b5c853735/src/number.rs#L364-L366) that will cause that `String` to be emitted as a number in JSON. You could now abuse this and emit that internal field name yourself, but more cleanly, I would just convert `BigDecimal` to `serde_json::Number`. The sad part is that `serde_json::Number` and `BigDecimal` don't trust each other, so the only way to convert between them is through parsing a string. Armed with that knowledge:

```ini
serde_json = { version = "1.0.95", features = ["arbitrary_precision"] }
```

```rust
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default)]
pub struct Product {
    pub name: String,
    #[serde(serialize_with = "bigdec_as_num")]
    pub price: BigDecimal,
}

fn bigdec_as_num<S: serde::Serializer>(n: &BigDecimal, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
    n.to_string()
        .parse::<serde_json::Number>()
        .map_err(serde::ser::Error::custom)
        .and_then(|n| n.serialize(s))
}

fn main() {
    println!(
        "{}",
        serde_json::to_string_pretty(&Product {
            name: "foo".to_string(),
            price: "1000000000000000000.000000000000000000000000000000000001".parse().unwrap(),
        })
        .unwrap()
    );
}
```

Comment: I assume you meant: "it's probably a **bad** idea to serialize BigDecimals as numbers"?